# Removing duplicates from List<double[]>

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I am trying to remove the duplicates from a list of double arrays. I would like to keep the first instance of the duplicate but remove any found after.

Here is my code:

```
private static List<double[]> RemoveDupes(List<double[]> locData)
    {
        List<double[]> list = locData;
        while (ContainsDupes(list))
            for (int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++)
                for (int b = 0; b < list.Count; b++)
                    if (a != b && list[a][0] == list[b][0] && list[a][1] == list[b][1])
                        list.RemoveAt(b);

        return list;
    }
private static bool ContainsDupes(List<double[]> list)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++)
            for (int b = 0; b < list.Count; b++)
                if (a != b && list[a][0] == list[b][0] && list[a][1] == list[b][1])
                    return true;
        return false;
    }
```

This method works almost all of the time but it's slow and in edge cases (1 out of a few thousand) it crashes my program with an index exception on line 6. I can't think of any other way to do this so any help would be appreciated.

Input:

```
{{45.5, 23.6}, {34.54, 98.34}, {45.5, 23.6}}
```

Desired output:

```
{{45.5, 23.6}, {34.54, 98.34}}
```

(length of the double[] is always 2)

Comment: `list.RemoveAt(b);` actually removes whole `double[]` array inside `List<double[]>`, not just a duplicate element. Is that intended?

Comment: Can you use LINQ? If so did you take a look at IEnumerable.Distinct()?

Comment: Honestly your code seems hard to understand, why do you check for 2 different values in each loop? Can you provide us with some entries and the expected output?

Comment: Instead of cycling twice to first get the element and then remove it, maybe `ContainsDupes` can return the duplicate (or null if there's none). Then the `while` could be as such: `double[] temp; while ((temp = ContainsDupes(list)) != null) list.Remove(temp);`

Comment: @DarjanBogdan `list.RemoveAt(b);` removing the whole array is intentional.

Comment: @Joelius I have tried using IEnumerable.Distinct() and it does not work.

Comment: @nalnpir The length of the double[] is always 2. I have edited the post with the desired output.

Comment: Well a single distinct won't work since arrays are reference-types. You'd have to cast them to a list of tuples for example (because tuples are value-types so the value gets compared, not the reference).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you've stated that array will always be size of 2, I suggest you to use different data type. For example, [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) would be more appropriate, because these are actually pairs of values.

For example, you could define a collection of pairs:

`List<(double, double)> pairs = new List<(double, double)>(); //C# 7.1+`

`List<Tuple<double, double>> pairsCollection = new List<Tuple<double, double>>(); // C# 7 or less`

Seed it in this manner:

```
pairs.Add((45.5, 23.6));
pairs.Add((34.54, 98.34));
pairs.Add((45.5, 23.6));
```

And than, just use `Distinct` method, to remove duplicates:

```
pairs.Distinct();
```

This would output:

> {{45.5, 23.6}, {34.54, 98.34}}

In addition, if you are not able to change the data type, you can project the collection into collection of pairs, and than distinct it:

```
List<double[]> collection = new List<double[]>()
{
    new double[]{45.5, 23.6},
    new double[]{34.54, 98.34},
    new double[]{45.5, 23.6}
};
var pairs = collection.Select(pa => (pa[0], pa[1])); 
var distinctPairs = pairs.Distinct();
```

Comment: The second one is a great and clean solution, however the OP would still need a way to go back to `List<double[]>` in the end.

Comment: @StackLloyd its all good I converted to and from the tuple with foreach and a minute or so of googling

Comment: I've now rewritten my program for tuples and I found that removing dupes from an array can easily be done `array.Distinct().ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__

```
var l = new List<int[]>(){
            new int[]{5,4,3},
            new int[]{5,4,3},
            new int[]{5,4,2},
            };

            var indexStore = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < l.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int x = i + 1; x < l.Count-1; x++)
                {
                    if (l[i].SequenceEqual(l[x]))
                    {
                        indexStore.Add(x);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var index in indexStore)
            {
                l.RemoveAt(index);
            }
```

Do not remove while looping better store the duplicate indexes